# A Commutator Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that in a group $G$, if $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$ and $x^y$ is defined to be $y^{-1}xy$, then we have the following identities: $$[x,yz]=[x,z][x,y]^z;$$ $$[x^n, y^n]=[x,y]^n,$$ where $x,y,z\in G$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. My question is, is there any identity for $[x,y^n]$?

Comment: It is not true in general that $[x^n,y^n] = [x,y]^n$. It is not even true in $S_3$ with $n=2$.

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking about $[x^z, y^z]=[x,y]^z$ instead of $[x^n, y^n]=[x,y]^n$.

Comment: I think that $[a,b^n]=([a,b]^n)^{b^{n-1}}$; is it correct?

Comment: No, $[a,b^n] = [a,b][a,b]^b[a,b]^{b^2} \cdots [a,b]^{b^{n-1}}$, which is not the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following facts are satisfied when $x,y\in G$ are commutable with $[x,y]$:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb Z,~[x^n,y]=[x,y]^n=[x,y^n],\\ \forall n\ge 0~~~(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n-1)/2},~~[x,y^{-n}]=[x,y^{-1}]^n$$

**Source:** *An Introduction to the theory of Groups by J.J.Rotman*, Lemma 5.42.

Comment: Nice answer, Babak +1

Answer (score 1):

The identity
$$
[x^n, y^n]=[x,y]^n
$$
is not true. A counter-example: the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$.

As to your question, I think there is nothing better than

$$
[x,y^n]=[x,y][x^{y},y]\ldots [x^{y^{n-1}},y]
$$

Comment: Oh thanks! I was thinking about $[x^z, y^z]=[x,y]^z$ instead of $[x^n, y^n]=[x,y]^n$.